# Responsive Table with grid-template-areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this table working the way I want using `grid-template-areas`, collapsing columns on smaller screens, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do the css than what I currently have?

Feels like there has to be a better solution that I'm missing other than adding a new class for every new row in the table.

Code pen example has it working the way I want, using 2 columns on screens smaller than 800px: https://codepen.io/BigProof/pen/gOEzeJv

Large screen:

| H1 | H2 | H3 | H4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 |
| T11 | T22 | T33 | T44 |

Smaller screen:

| H1 | H2 |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | T2 |
| T11 | T22 |
| H3 | H4 |
| T3 | T4 |
| T33 | T44 |

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #15202b
}

.grid {
  color: #eee;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "Heading1 Heading2 Heading3 Heading4" "Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4" "Text11 Text22 Text33 Text44" "Text111 Text222 Text333 Text444";
  grid-gap: 6px;
  background-color: #224263;
  padding: 6px;
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: #15202b;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "Heading1 Heading2" "Text1 Text2" "Text11 Text22" "Text111 Text222" "Heading3 Heading4" "Text3 Text4" "Text33 Text44" "Text333 Text444";
  }
}

.Heading1,
.Heading2,
.Heading3,
.Heading4 {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Heading1 {
  grid-area: Heading1;
}

.Heading2 {
  grid-area: Heading2;
}

.Heading3 {
  grid-area: Heading3;
}

.Heading4 {
  grid-area: Heading4;
}

.Text1 {
  grid-area: Text1;
}

.Text11 {
  grid-area: Text11;
}

.Text111 {
  grid-area: Text111;
}

.Text2 {
  grid-area: Text2;
}

.Text22 {
  grid-area: Text22;
}

.Text222 {
  grid-area: Text222;
}

.Text3 {
  grid-area: Text3;
}

.Text33 {
  grid-area: Text33;
}

.Text333 {
  grid-area: Text333;
}

.Text4 {
  grid-area: Text4;
}

.Text44 {
  grid-area: Text44;
}

.Text444 {
  grid-area: Text444;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="Heading1">Heading1</div>
  <div class="Heading2">Heading2</div>
  <div class="Heading3">Heading3</div>
  <div class="Heading4">Heading4</div>
  <div class="Text1">Text1</div>
  <div class="Text11">Text11</div>
  <div class="Text111">Text111</div>
  <div class="Text2">Text2</div>
  <div class="Text22">Text22</div>
  <div class="Text222">Text222</div>
  <div class="Text3">Text3</div>
  <div class="Text33">Text33</div>
  <div class="Text333">Text333</div>
  <div class="Text4">Text4</div>
  <div class="Text44">Text44</div>
  <div class="Text444">Text444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Please make the code you have given consistent. At the moment the area definitions have h1, h2 etc but the remaining CSS has Heading1, Heading2 etc.

Comment: Fixed code. Any tips on making css code smarter for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: The table you show does not match your code (my answer currently is for the original table contents).

Comment: Your code is indeed more efficient and what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method woruld be to alter the HTML so it flowed in rows (for the wider case) naturally and then in the two column case explictly put items into their correct rows where necessary.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #15202b
  }
  
  .grid {
    color: #eee;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    background-color: #224263;
    padding: 6px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  .grid>div {
    background-color: #15202b;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  .Heading {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .grid :nth-child(3),
    .grid :nth-child(4) {
      grid-row: 5;
    }
    .grid :nth-child(7),
    .grid :nth-child(8) {
      grid-row: 6;
    }
    .grid :nth-child(11),
    .grid :nth-child(12) {
      grid-row: 7;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="Heading">Heading1</div>
  <div class="Heading">Heading2</div>
  <div class="Heading">Heading3</div>
  <div class="Heading">Heading4</div>
  <div>Text1</div>
  <div>Text2</div>
  <div>Text3</div>
  <div>Text4</div>
  <div>Text11</div>
  <div>Text22</div>
  <div>Text33</div>
  <div>Text44</div>
  <div>Text111</div>
  <div>Text222</div>
  <div>Text333</div>
  <div>Text444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is indeed more efficient and what I was looking for, thank you!